# how to develope primefaces responsive toolbar

Tags: primefaces, toolbar

I would like develop a  primefaces responsive toolbar .
How can I do it?

Thank you.

Testing my sample, it does not work in responsive mode.

```xml
<ui:composition>

  <h:form styleClass="app-form">

    <p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true" />
    <p:toolbar styleClass="app-ui-toolbar">

      <f:facet name="left">
        <!--                l'attributo height determina l'altezza della toolbar -->
        <p:graphicImage styleClass="app-ui-image-toolbar" id="gym" height="100%" url="/img/gym.png" />

        <ui:include src="/template/common/separatore.xhtml" />
        <p:outputLabel style="color:#FAFAFA" value="Gymnasium" />

        <ui:include src="/template/common/separatore.xhtml" />
        <p:commandLink styleClass="app-ui-link-toolbar" action="#{homeService.registratiPage}" value="#{mnu.MNURegistrazione}" />

        <ui:include src="/template/common/separatore.xhtml" />
        <p:commandLink styleClass="app-ui-link-toolbar" action="#{homeService.loginPage}" value="#{mnu.MNULogin}" />
      </f:facet>

      <f:facet name="right">
      </f:facet>

    </p:toolbar>

  </h:form>

</ui:composition>
```

Comment: 1: Always post version info. 2: What does the documentation say? Should it be responsive? This toolbar just does not have a responsive mode afaik

Comment: I think primefaces is a responsive platform....What do you suggest me ?

Comment: PrimeFaces is a component framework of which many (not all) components have some form of responsiveness in them. A large part of responsiveness is done via CSS and media queries. With not to much effort you can change the look of the toolbar to have each element below the other. But if you want more, like fully hiding and opening with a hamburger type icon, that requires a little more work, but for this small javascript plugins are available too (e.g. check the PrimeFaces elite themes)

Comment: I think to use the responsive grid tag, to design the tool bar......I can customize them  witch css, like a tool bar.What do you think about it?

Comment: Yes, that is a creative option... it might work and  be indeed simple.